# Is Java's exception handling mechanism an example of the Chain of Responsibility design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, exception

I have been reading about the ***Chain of Responsibility*** design pattern which basically allows a decoupling between the sender of a request and receiver of the request. The request can be passed along a chain until someone is ready to consume the request. Now in Java when we specify that a method is capable of throwing an `Exception`  we let the caller of the method handle the exception. If it is not interested it can further propagate the exception up the chain. So can this process be cited as an application of the ***Chain of Responsibility*** design pattern?

Comment: Also note that you can think of virtual method dispatching as a chain of responsibility. The method call will be serviced by the first class that "implements" the method, from most derived upwards in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. Exception handling in Java is based on Chain of responsibility pattern
In this pattern:

1. Sender will not know which object in the chain will serve its
   request
2. Each node in the chain may decide to serve the request --> catching an exception and
   wrapping it with an Application specific exception
3. Each  node can forward the request --> throwing exception to the immediate caller
4. None of the node can serve the request --> Leaves the job with the caller

Hence, Exception handling is a Chain of responsibility pattern

Comment: There is a minor conceptual similarity. None whatsoever in the implementation. There is no 'source of command objects' and no 'series of processing objects'.

Comment: This is wrong answer as Exception hierarchy is based on Inheritance and chain of responsibility is filter processor on requests.